# Symfony2 - Rewrite url to add www prefixwith existing .htacess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, url-rewriting

Symfony2 core configuration comes up with the following .htacess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I understand that this will erase the app.php from the url in the browser.
I would like to add the following rewrite rule to add www. to my WebSite everytime a user enter the domain name without the www. :

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^valutao\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.valutao.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So now i have the following .htacess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^valutao\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.valutao.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

My issue is that app.php will show up again. It seems that my rule just hides the base configuration. Here is an example of what is displayed in the url when I enter valutao.com : http://www.valutao.com/app.php

Does someone know how to fix that. Unfortunately I have just basic knowledge with the rewrite rules.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

You simply need to change the order (www rewrite should go first).

I'd also make it less dependent on the  domain name:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: With this, I was able to remove the app.php part. How would I remove also the /Symfony/web part? (So, rewrite http://www.mydomain.com/Symfony/web/app.php/main to http://www.mydomain.com/main. Thanks a lot